# DataflowRunner exits with "No files to stage has been found."

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to run the `WordCount` java example from https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/, but somehow I get an error that no files to stage have been found by the `ClasspathScanningResourcesDetector`. I run the example exactly as described on the website:

```
 mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
     -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=<your-gcp-project> \
                  --gcpTempLocation=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/tmp \
                  --inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/* --output=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/counts" \
     -Pdataflow-runner
```

, which yields

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:214)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No files to stage has been found.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:281)
    ... 10 more
```

I am using the latest beam version

```
<beam.version>2.19.0</beam.version>
```

Do you know how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
This is a bug in 2.19.0. It works in 2.18.0

**EDIT:**
I am using Redhat OpenJDK 8 on Windows

**EDIT:**
Also, some unit test are failing from the standard wordcount example

DebuggingWordCountTest fails with

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec: /Users/<redacted>/AppData/Local/Temp/junit7907687962995108435/junit2682353785908929665.tmp

    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:321)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you replaced <your-gcp-project> and  <your-gcs-bucket> with actual values ? Also, can you confirm the Java version that you are running the job with?

Comment: Yes, I did that, but didn't want to show it here

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? Some members of my team are experiencing this issue, and we think it might be an issue only on Windows.

Comment: @samwagg Yes, I am on Windows and I tested with Redhat OpenJDK 8 and 11  and I have set the maven compiler target to 1.8. I don't know whether Java 11 is supported at this time at all. That is why I use Java 8 now.

Comment: @Florian, we are using java 8 as well. So far the only thing all cases I know of have in common is that they are on Windows. I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9471#.

Comment: I ran into the same problem in Windows 10, dropping down to 2.18 fixed it. It sounds like there is a fix coming in 2.20. (according to BEAM-9471)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you are running the dataflow it will try to find and upload the
  dependencies.
- I assume you are getting error "No files to stage has
  been found" due some classpath issue.
- Try to use the --filesToStage
  option to manually provide the jars or classes to stage

Also Provided sample logs which successfully copied 114 files to stage so you can compare with your complete logs to understand the issue.

```
Mar 08, 2020 7:37:41 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions$StagingLocationFactory create
INFO: No stagingLocation provided, falling back to gcpTempLocation
Mar 08, 2020 7:37:42 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 114 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Mar 08, 2020 7:37:43 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline on the Dataflow Service, which will have billing implications related to Google Compute Engine usage and other Google Cloud Services.
Mar 08, 2020 7:37:43 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Uploading 114 files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to staging location to prepare for execution.
Mar 08, 2020 7:37:48 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Staging files complete: 114 files cached, 0 files newly uploaded
```

You can try the below commands to generate the source code required and run the pipeline freshly to stage dependencies.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.8.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=first-dataflow \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Also you can try it in qwiklabs for free:
https://google.qwiklabs.com/focuses/7974?parent=catalog

Comment: I actually used this generate command. I will upvote your answer, as soon as I can upvote

Comment: It just doesn't pick up the compiled classes from the classpath. I know about the "--filesToStage" option, but I think it should pick it up automatically. Maybe this is a bug and I should open an issue?

Comment: The pipeline ran without any issue with -DarchetypeVersion=2.19.0 for beam version 2.19.0 and openjdk version "1.8.0_242".