# Google Cloud Dataflow input collections number of elements added is not consistent with number of elements inserted into BigQuery?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I currently have a Google Cloud Dataflow job that consumes messages from a Google Cloud PubSub subscription and writes the results to BigQuery using Load Jobs every 2 minutes. However, I seem to be actually writing less rows to BigQuery than the number of elements added displayed in the Google Cloud Dataflow UI for the WriteToBigQuery step:

[image: Dataflow Diagram]

[image]

The amount of rows written to BigQuery were only around 200,000. After looking through the StackDriver logs, there were a few Info level logs stating that the job failed and a retry was taking place, but there were no indication of why the job was failing. There were no explicit errors that occurred, apart from one with the following message:

```
 "Request failed with code 409, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying)"
```

The HTTP resource included with the message was:

```
{ "error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Login Required.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "location": "Authorization",
    "locationType": "header"
  }
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"}}
```

The error was also followed by another Info level log with the following message (along with the 409 Exception code again):

```
BigQuery job {jobId=insert_job_id, location=US, project=project_id} already exists, will not retry inserting it:
```

There should not be any authentication errors as otherwise none of the rows would be written to BigQuery so I am rather confused here. Is there any other way to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I was thinking about this, and I am not too sure what to advise. (1) The error you are seeing, of a single bigquery job failing isn't itself an issue if the pipeline completes successfully, and if it successfully retries the bq job. A duplicate job warning, is just a detection that job was attempted to be launched twice. Neither of these in theory would cause data loss. The counters themselves perhaps have some sort of issue. But taking a look at the BigqueryIO code, I don't see anything catching exceptions to prevent the elements from being retried. There could be a non obvious bug though.

Comment: Would you also consider updating your beam SDK to the latest version, 2.19.0,  if you have not already and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm currently using the 2.18.0 Beam SDK because when I tried to use 2.19.0, I was receiving this error: "Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions): InvocationTargetException: No files to stage has been found." even without making any code or command line argument changes. Do you know how this could be resolved by any chance?

Comment: Which version of java are you using? I have seen some threads online of users encountering this with java 9, though beam recommends java 8 should be used.

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

Comment: There is also a suggestion here to pass in the jars to stage manually using maven, based on the theory that there is some issue preventing the program from automatically finding them on the classpath.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586141/dataflowrunner-exits-with-no-files-to-stage-has-been-found

Comment: Normally you should not specify the --filesToStage parameter at all, doing so incorrectly could also cause this error

Comment: I'm currently using Java 8, and I do not specify the --filesToStage parameter using a command line argument. I will try manually setting the filesToStage to the jars needed.

Comment: Hello @eagerbeaver, did you manage to update your beam SDK to 2.19.0 or to solve your issue?
If the issue persists, I'd recommend you to contact [Google Cloud Platform technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) in order to get this issue resolved.